# Как найти сумму минимального положительного элемента рандомного массива и его номера на Java

Tags: java, массивы

не могу решить задание (только начал учить Java)

Comment: В какой момент у Вас возникла проблема решения этой задачи?

Comment: в момент нахождения минимального положительного элемента рандомного массива

Comment: тогда самый простой вариант. пробегитесь циклом по массиву, в начале цикла присвойте временной переменной значение элемента массива по индексу [0], дальше сравнивайте каждый элемент массива с индексом итерации цикла со временной переменной и если значение элемента будет меньше значения переменной то присваивайте значение элемента в переменную...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим у вас есть какой-то массив arr:

```
 List<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

Заполним его данными:

```
 for(int i=-100;i<100;i++){
     arr.add(i);
 }
```

Найдем максимальный положительный элемент:

```
 Optional<Integer> max = arr
     .stream()
     .filter(s->s>0)
     .max(Integer::compareTo);
```

Тестируем:

```
System.out.print(max.isPresent() ? max.get() : "Такого числа нет");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]